# 403 Error on Stylesheet - Raspberry Pi Webserver

Tags: css, linux, web, webserver, raspberry-pi

I keep seeing a 403 error for my stylesheet which is hosted on my Rasberry Pi (webserver). I ran ls -al and this is the result:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/www $ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   root 4096 Mar 17 20:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Mar 15 16:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   root  644 Mar 17 20:18 index.html
-rw-------  1 pi   root  329 Mar 17 20:19 stylesheet.css
```

The index.html data shows up when I point my browser at the ip, but there is no formatting and whenever I try to acess the css file through looking at the source code it keeps telling me theres a 403 error :(

Can anyone help a brother out??

Cheers!

Comment: You'll need to change the permissions of the stylesheet, currently it's set to user read/write but not group or world permissions.

Comment: is that what the -rw------- means? How do I go about changing it?

Comment: Hey guys,

if anyone has a similar problem I fixed it by changing the permissions for the stylesheet using:

    sudo chmod 644 stylesheet.css

Here is a quick guide I found: http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/

and here is a decent explanation of what is going on: http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_file_permissions

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need proper permissions for the www folder, and that depends on which webserver you are running. For apache on debian the user is www-data, if your webroot is ~/www and you are user pi try these commands

- Change owner to apache user recursively
- Change Permissions to read for all recursively

  chown -R www-data:www-data /home/pi/www

  chmod -R 644 /home/pi/www